# When controlling for confounders in a causal study, should we always expect a decrease in the treatment effect estimate?

Tags: causality, treatment-effect

In a causal study, can treatment effect go up upon applying causal techniques when comparing with the naive / simple difference in means? I think this question is method-agnostic, but for transparency the method I was working with was matching + outcome model.

To be more specific, my question is in 2 parts:

1. *Can* treatment effect go up when controlling for confounders? (Where the covariates you control for are actually confounders, as opposed to variables we should not have controlled for, and there are no issues with the analysis design - assume perfect setup, including the unconfoundness assumption)
2. If the above is true, practically speaking, is this rare? Or is it not rare enough that when it happens, you wouldn't wonder if something is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the treatment effect *can* go up after adjusting for confounding. Take the simple example of a continuous treatment ($A$), continuous confounder ($Z$), and continuous outcome ($Y$). If $Z$ is negatively correlated with the treatment and positively correlated with the outcome (or vice versa), The adjusted estimate for $A$ will be larger (i.e., more positive) than the unadjusted/crude estimate.

Intuitively, if the kinds of people who have high $A$ also tend to have low $Z$, and $Z$ is positively correlated with $Y$, then the crude effect of increasing $A$ is asking: how much does the mean of $Y$ change when comparing the kinds of people with low $A$ (who tend to have high $Z$) to the kinds of people with high $A$ (who tend to have low $Z$).

Here's a demonstration in R:

```
gen_data <- function(n,seed){
  set.seed(seed)
  Z <- rnorm(n)
  A <- -1*Z + rnorm(n)
  Y <- A + Z + rnorm(n)
  data.frame(Z,A,Y)
}

df <- gen_data(100000, seed = 123)

unadj <- lm(Y ~ A, data = df)

adj <- lm(Y ~ A + Z, data = df)

coef(unadj)["A"]
0.5031301 

coef(adj)["A"]
1.000054
```

How common this scenario is I'm not sure. It seems highly context dependent. Though it's not something that, in my experience, would be considered rare. It's pretty easy to come up with examples.